# Fetch record from 1st table which are not in 2nd table mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join, where-clause

I have following records in these two mysql tables.

Table-A

```
       Question_No 
           1
           2
           3
           4
           5
```

Table-B

```
Roll_No  Question_No  Ans_Option
 1001      1         NULL 
 1001      2         D
 1001      3         NULL
 1002      1         C
 1002      2         NULL
```

Here the word "NULL" is explicitly inserted into column , nothing to be confused.

How can I display the following result by mysql query?

```
       Questions not attempted by roll no 1001 are : 1, 3, 4, 5 
       Questions not attempted by roll no 1002 are : 2, 3, 4, 5
```

I tried with following code but not working

```
select distinct a.* from table_A a NATURAL LEFT JOIN table_B b where 
b.Question_No IS NULL and b.Roll_No=1001;// where I am wrong here ? I have 
not set any column as primary key , should I set?
```

Thanks a lot in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put `WHERE` condition on `LEFT OUTER JOIN` it is literally the same as `INNER JOIN`:

```
select distinct a.* 
from table_A a 
NATURAL LEFT JOIN table_B b 
where b.Question_No IS NULL 
  and b.Roll_No=1001;  -- this condition makes it `NATURAL JOIN`
```

You could rewrite it as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*
FROM table_A a
LEFT JOIN table_b b
  ON a.Question_No = b.Question_No
 AND b.Roll_No=1001
WHERE b.Ans_Option_No IS NULL
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cc38ef5c4d2f7021d6158c02a40b2cb3)**

Comment: thanks for helping me but I am getting values for roll no 1001 : 3, 4, 5, how can I get 1, 3, 4, 5?

Comment: @Tom `WHERE b.Ans_Option_No IS NULL1`

Comment: okay how can I add" b.Question_No is NULL " along with above code which u had written earlier ?

Comment: hi I am not getting questions which Ans_No contain NULL values, I am getting questions 3, 4 , 5 but not 1, 3 , 4, 5

Comment: @Tom Did you run the code? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cc38ef5c4d2f7021d6158c02a40b2cb3

Comment: I have not set any columns as primary key? Should I set Question_No as primary key in both the tables ?

Comment: Thanks a lot Lukasz, I got it by adding following condition: where b.Ans_Option_No IS NULL OR b.Ans_Option_No='NULL';

Answer (score 1):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows and then filter them out:

```
select r.roll_no, b.Question_No
from (select distinct roll_no from b) r cross join
     a left join
     b
     on b.roll_no = r.roll_no and b.Question_No = a.Question_No
where b.roll_no is null;
```

This gets the question that are *not* in `b`.

Comment: thanks a lot for helping me out...will this query result faster or the solution provided by Lukasz ?

Comment: @Tom . . . They implement different logic.  I think this is the version that you actually want.